# mocha mocking imported variable

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js

This is my module and the function i want to test:

```
import aVariable from 'aModule'

export function afunction() {
  //do something with the imported aVariable 
  //calculates result
  return result
});
```

I want to mock aVariable for my mocha unit test.

```
import {afunction} from 'aModule.js'

describe('Tests', () => {
  it('should return expected', () => {
    expect(afunction()).to.equal(expected);
  });
```

Is this possible?

UPDATE:

Use of babel-rewire-plugin my .babelrc:

```
{
  "env": {
    "dev": {
      "presets": ["es2015"]
    },
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["rewire"]
    }
  }
}
```

When i run my test with:

```
meteor test --meteortesting:mocha
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: _getServiceUrl(...).__Rewire__ is not a function
```

and when i use:

```
BABEL_ENV=test meteor test --meteortesting:mocha
```

i get:

```
While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):
/node_modules/rewire/lib/rewire.js:19:15: Filename must be a string
```

Comment: Have you seen the [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-rewire) plugin for babel?  it allows you to easily do such things.  Also there is [another rewire library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) that you can use if you aren't using babel.

Comment: I have seen rewire but i was not aware that you can mockup imports with i and I use Babel as a transpiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally mock these ES6 imports by using https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js

with the `testDouble.replace()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have the babel-plugin-rewire node module installed you can do the following in your test:

```
describe('Tests', () => {
  it('should return expected', () => {
    afunction.__Rewire__( 'aVariable', 'myStubVariableValue' );
    expect(afunction()).to.equal(expected);
    afunction.__ResetDependency__( 'aVariable' );
});
```

Comment: will try this out asap

Comment: I tried, but i am getting undefined errors when it comes to access `x.__Rewire__`. Do i need some imports?

Comment: @Gobliins do you have the [babel rewire plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-rewire) installed?

Comment: Try adding this to your .babelrc file `"env": { "test": { "plugins": ["rewire"] } }`

Comment: still i am getting `TypeError: aFunction(...).__Rewire__ is not a function ` , i have posted my ` .babelrc ` see update in my question

Comment: When you use `__Rewire__` you use it on the module that you've imported as opposed to the result of the calling the module that you've imported.  So if I want to rewire the `api` module that is imported in the `aFunction` module then I would do `aFunction.__Rewire__('api', myApiStub)`

Comment: Ok a big problem i run into is that sometimes the path of the module is not present, since its created afterwards by a framework (meteor) on top of node where my tests run. Is rewire able to fake the non existing path `import Meteor from 'meteor/meteor'` if it does not exist?

Answer (score -1):

You should add --require babel to your mocha run script